# RxSwift Combine Array of observables with array of objects

Tags: swift, firebase, observable, rx-swift

I'm trying to fetch data from Firebase using RxSwift. I'm using [this](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxFirebase) to perform API calls.

So my db looks like this:
Collection **Category** (it has properties: title, about etc) has inside of it another collection called **Manifests**. To get **Manifests** I need to use `documentId` of **Category** collection. So it's two different API calls but I want to combine results

That is what I have so far:

```
    func fetchCategories() -> Observable<[ManifestCategory]> {
        let ref = self.db.collection(FirebaseCollection.manifestCategories.collectionPath)

        return ref.rx.getDocuments().map({ snapshot in
            return snapshot.documents.map({ doc in
                var category = ManifestCategory.init(JSON: doc.data())

                category?.documentId = doc.documentID

                return category
                }).compactMap({ $0 })
        })
    }

    func fetchManifests(categoryId: String) -> Observable<[Manifest]> {
        let ref = self.db.collection(FirebaseCollection.manifests(categoryId: categoryId).collectionPath)

        return ref.rx.getDocuments().map({ snapshot in
            return snapshot.documents.map({ doc in
                var manifest = Manifest.init(JSON: doc.data())

                manifest?.documentId = doc.documentID

                return manifest
            }).compactMap({ $0 })
        })
    }
```

Is there any way I can put **Manifests** array into **Category** object?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try something like this:

```
func fetchCategories() -> Observable<[ManifestCategory]> {
    let ref = self.db.collection(FirebaseCollection.manifestCategories.collectionPath)

    return ref.rx.getDocuments()
        .map { snapshot in
            return snapshot.documents
                .map { doc in
                    var category = ManifestCategory.init(JSON: doc.data())
                    category?.documentId = doc.documentID
                    return category
                }
                .compactMap { $0 }
        }
        .flatMapLatest { [weak self] categories -> Observable<[ManifestCategory]> in
            guard let self = self else {
                return .empty()
            }

            let observables = categories.map { category -> ([Manifest], String) in
                self.fetchManifests(categoryId: category.documentId)
                    .map { ($0, category.documentId) }
            }

            return Observable.zip(observables)
                .map { tuple -> [ManifestCategory] in
                    tuple.compactMap { manifests, id in
                        if var category = categories.first(where: { $0.documentId == id }) {
                            category.manifests = manifests
                            return category
                        }
                        return nil
                    }
                }
        }
}
```